# Is it advisable to integrate jQuery with richfaces + SEAM?

Tags: jquery, richfaces, seam

Is it advisable to integrate jQuery with richfaces + SEAM ? or it is enough to handle the jQuery stuff using richfaces.

Comment: When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a jQuery application, and want to use some Richfaces components, have a look at [my blog](http://shervinasgari.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-use-jquery-with-richfaces.html) where I describe how you can integrate it.

Comment: Thank you..its very helful..:)

Answer (score 1):

RichFaces is shipped with jQuery. Using that built-in jQuery is perfectly correct.

You can load that build-in jQuery library by adding the following to your page:

```
<a4j:loadScript src="resource:///org/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/jquery/jquery.js"/>
```